# Jackson deserialization: How to get a default value even if the JSON property was null

Tags: jackson, jersey, deserialization

In my project I'm using Jersey 2.23.1 with Jackson for JSON support.

When I'm getting a request with something like `{ "foo":null, "bar":"123" }` as JSON, matching with `class A{String foo; String bar;}` Jersey first creates and instance of A (with default values if specified in constructor), then deserialize JSON to a temporary object A', then copies all JSON fields that were specified in JSON from A' to A. If I have default values in A-class constructor, and have fields equal to null in JSON, all my default values are erased and replaced by null. So in the example above, if I have a default value for the `foo` field, it will be replaced by null in the object Jersey will return as param for my `@Path` annotated method.

I'm using `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` on `A` class to avoid the transfer of null fields during Response. But it only works for serialization, what about deserialization? I mean, when having `{ "foo":null }` as JSON results in field "foo" = null in new object instance after deserialization.

Here is some code to sum all of this :

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(value = Include.NON_NULL)
public class User {
    public enum EUserRole {
        PARENT, STUDENT, PROF, ADMIN
    }

    @Id
    public String id;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public EUserRole role;

    public User() {
         id = ObjectId.get().toString();
         role = EUserRole.STUDENT;
         lastName = "RandomLastName";
    }
}
```

if I'm passing this kind of JSON

```
{
    "id":null,
    "lastName":null,
    "firstName":"Random First Name",
    "role":"STUDENT"
}
```

to my method (in controller)

```
@POST
public Response createUser(final User entity) {
}
```

it results that all null fields in JSON are set to null in my entity and not set to the constructor default values.

Do you know if there is a way to specify Jackson to ignore null fields during deserialization? Or is this a Jersey-related behavior?

Comment: AFAIK, this question applies to Jackson in general. Also, the symptoms are the same regardless of whether the default values are set in the constructor or in variable initializers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to ignore data from JSON payload in that sense, based on value contained (you can use ignoral to just ignore all values for given property).
So if you want to avoid null assignment, you need define a setter that will just swallow `null` value (that is, only assign non-null).

Ability to prevent `null` assignment might a useful feature to add via `@JsonFormat.Feature`, something like:

```
// hypothetical no such feature exists yes
@JsonFormat(without = JsonFormat.Feature.ALLOW_NULL_ASSIGNMENT)
```

so perhaps this could be a feature request.

And the reason I think this belongs to per-property handling is that this seems like a specific rule for some of the properties. Although perhaps there could also be a matching global setting if it seems users really like such null-ignoral.